# How to store HTML-Page inside QRCode?

Tags: html, qr-code

i would like to create a QR-Code containing a very simple website. The problem is, i would like to store the page inside the QR-Code, not as a url pointing to a website. So the qr-code contains the source code to the whole page and works without internet.

My first though was to store the page inside the qr-code as a data url. Eg. "data:text/html;...". This does theoreticly work but so far i didn't find a qr-code scanner which is able to open it in a way the page would be displayed.

I found out some qr-code scanners open content starting with "javascript:" in the browser but i wasn't able to display a page that way either. (With "window.open" or "document.write" as example).

My best guess to create a qr-code, which most qr-code scanners would open in a browser, is to create one starting with http://. But i dont know a way to store the html source code in a url starting with http://.

Any help would be welcome :)

Comment: First: You would need to create your own QR-Code Scanner because other scanners will not know how to display your text.
Second: The more data is in a QR-Code the more complex it will become (bigger!) you'd need a very big diplay to get lot of HTML in this QR-Code

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. Even though building a custom QR-Code Scanner shouldn't be that much of a hassle, it would sadly not fit my requirements. The whole idea would be for anyone to scan the code and be able to see the page. With or without internet available to them and without previously downloading a certain qr-code scanner ...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm trying to do the same thing and right now I'm thinking I'll add instructions by the QR code to manually copy and paste the text into the URL bar (which works for me).  I considered publishing an app that would handle the data URI scheme (or another scheme) the way I want it to, but since the internet would be required for the download, I don't think I will.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Data:` Url Protocol and put your HTML directly into the URL Like a Link. Mozilla Guide here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

data:text/html,{html of your page}

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the browsers are going to block Data: URI for security reasons. The same for Javascript: URI.